# Setting geometry through Pandoc API

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I have a really wide table that I converted to a pandoc table format and used pandoc command line tool to set paperwidth to 20in like below (for pdf output) - just a prototype using pandoc command line tool:

```
<processed input piped to pandoc here> | pandoc -V geometry:margin=.1in 
-V geometry:paperwidth=20in <other options>
```

Is there any way to set those variables using Pandoc haskell api? I will like to parse the CSV to pandoc (using [`Fuel.hs`](https://gist.github.com/stephenjbarr/11c23e99febd19dccfbd) from Bayhac 2014 which also includes pandoc generated default latex template), and then export to pdf after setting the paperwidth (calculated based on max length across rows in pdf) and margin.

Comment: so what exactly have you tried? where exactly do you want to set the geometry...? (there are multiple ways, e.g. yaml metadata) Also, take a look at (my) [pandoc-placetable](https://github.com/mb21/pandoc-placetable) filter if you want to include CSV data with pandoc...

Comment: Why use Pandoc at all? Not that it's bad or anything, but its current strengths lie in texts, not tables. Instead you could use something more specialized like LibreOffice calc - which, as far as I know, has a CLI too if you need something automatic.

Comment: @mb21, I generated a code-fence with csv inline in that code fence, and then passed it to pandoc after passing it through pandoc-csv2table. What I am trying to figure out is that if I have haskell code instead to generate `pandoc` from csv using `table` api, how do I set the geometry such as `paperwidth` in haskell code with `xelatex` engine? I have `Fuel.hs` from Bayhac 2014 that I am using as the base solution (with default latex template).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using pandoc as a library

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34485073/214446) for details, but basically you use the [`writeLaTeX`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/LaTeX.hs#L82) function with the right [`WriterOptions`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Options.hs#L336).

```
makePDF "xelatex" $ writeLaTeX opts document
  where
    opts = def {
      writerVariables = [("geometry","paperwidth=20in"), ("geometry", "margin=.1in")]
    }
```

#### How it works under the hood

Firstly, `geometry` is a template variable and not part of the document metadata (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26490978/214446)). As you can see in the [LaTeX Writer](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/LaTeX.hs#L246), the final output is generated with:

```
renderTemplate' template context
```

This uses the `renderTemplate'` function from [pandoc's own templating system](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Templates.hs). At the beginning of that file there's an extensive example and documentation how to use it programatically.

But basically something along the lines of:

```
import Text.Pandoc.Writers.Shared (defField)
import Text.Pandoc.Templates (renderTemplate')
import Data.Aeson (Value(Object))
import GHC.Exts (fromList)

let context = defField "geometry:paperwidth" "20in"
            $ defField "geometry:margin" ".1in"
            $ Object $ fromList []
renderTemplate' template context
```

#### Is it necessary?

I'm still not sure why you want to do all that in haskell code, since [pandoc filters](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) were explicitly designed to let you easily include data (like CSV with e.g. the [pandoc-placetable filter](https://github.com/mb21/pandoc-placetable)) in a document, without essentially having to reimplementing pandoc and its templating system etc.

Comment: I need to do it in haskell code since this is used in a Haskell websocket server for automatic document processing. It is more reliable error handling through API call instead of making a system call from Haskell.

Comment: I just tried your `makePDF` suggestion with `Fuel.hs` from BayHac2014 by adding geometry variables to `export` function. Then, I looked at the PDF size using inspector tool on Preview in mac, but still don't see it being set to new size. The new size shows up fine when using the command line. Perhaps I missed something here? The template is default latex template.

Comment: I have fixed the errors in the solution so that I can now accept it. I have also added some more details in my answer below so it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now. The key is to pass the variables in the format as below:

```
makePDF "xelatex" $ writeLaTeX opts document
  where
    opts = def {
      writerVariables = [("geometry","paperwidth=30in"), ("geometry", "margin=.1in")]
    }
```

For `Fuel.hs`, the `export` code becomes:

```
    export :: (MonadIO m) => String ->  Pandoc -> m (Either BL.ByteString BL.ByteString)
    export tmpl pdoc = liftIO $ makePDF "xelatex" 
      writeLaTeX (def { writerStandalone = True, writerTemplate = tmpl,
      writerVariables = [("geometry","paperwidth=30in"), ("geometry", 
      "margin=.1in")]}) pdoc
```

I have fixed @mb21's answer to reflect the fix.